# PIL - Open image is not able to be read

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Im trying to read a file's format so I can correctly assign a new name to it and write it to disk, but when the Image.open() is on the image, I cannot write the image to disk. So for example :

This works:

```
>>>file = open('708864.jpg')
>>> open('lala.jpeg', 'w').write(file.read())
```

But, this doesn't

```
>>>import Image
>>>im = Image.open('708864.jpg')
>>> im.format
>>> open('lala.jpeg', 'w').write(file.read())
```

It creates a corrupted file (lala.jpeg) which is unable to be opened by any software.
I'm suspecting the culprit is the Image.open(). And after trying to locate an Image.close() statement, I was unable to find one.  How would you "close" this image, so I can still write it to disk?

Comment: is not easier just rename file?

Comment: Where does `file` in the second script come from?  Also, if you're just trying to save the image, can't you call `im.save('lala.jpeg')`?

Comment: @SamMussmann oh wow, never knew about that function. That makes everything so much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help!  I've added an answer with `im.save` as well as a link to further documentation so you can find other fun things. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, `im.save('lala.jpg')` is the way to go.

For all the other fun methods on an `Image` object, you can look at the [documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#methods).

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround, it is just idea:

```
import Image
import StringIO

file = open('/home/mrok/1.jpg')
output = StringIO.StringIO(file.read())

im = Image.open('/home/mrok/1.jpg')
im.format

open('/home/mrok/2.jpg', 'w').write(output.getvalue())
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment, I ended up using a function I never knew about before, `Image.save()` , which quickly solves my problem.